# setting elements of a structure to random double values using an array of pointers to the structure

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make an array of pointers to a structure
the program runs, however it just says 'Segmentation fault: 11'
any help would be be very much appreciated

```
typedef struct
{
  int id;
  double x;
  double y;
  char name[30];
  int named;
} Star;


Star *stars[10];


int bang (int n_stars)
{
  if ((n_stars >= 1) && (n_stars <= 10))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_stars; i++)
    {
      double x = rand() % 10;
      double y = rand() % 10;
      stars[i] = (Star*) malloc(sizeof(x) + sizeof(y));
      stars[i]->x = x;
      stars[i]->y = y;
      free(stars[i]);
      return 1;
    }
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the statement:  `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: in the `bang()` function: These statements: `else
 {
     return 0;
 }` are not needed and just confuse the issue

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `double x = rand() % 10;`  the function: `rand()` returns an `int`, not a double

Comment: how are we to know that the parameter: `n_stars` is <=10?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `stars[i] = (Star*) malloc(sizeof(x) + sizeof(y));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  2)  the statement is the same as: `stars[i] = malloc( 2 * sizeof( double ) );` 3) the function: `malloc()` can fail.  so always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If ==NULL then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` , cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: before calling: `rand()` need to initialize the random number sequence.  An easy way is: `srand( (unsigned)time( void ) );`  the `srand()` should only be called once, at the beginning of `main()`

Comment: regarding: `free(stars[i]);`why throw away the heap memory allocation with out having ever used it.

Comment: regarding this statement: `return 1;` inside the `for()` loop.  The result is the execution of the code will never get pasted the first iteration of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of the argument, let us disregard struct alignment and assume a target (such as x86) where:

`sizeof(double) == 8`, and `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Now, you're allocating a block of memory 16 bytes in size:

`stars[i] = (Star*) malloc(sizeof(x) + sizeof(y));`

The definition of the struct is:

```
typedef struct
{
  int id;
  double x;
  double y;
  char name[30];
  int named;
} Star;
```

Note the offset of `y` is 12 bytes. When you perform:

`stars[i]->y = y;`

The value of `y` is written to the address `&stars[i]` + 12 bytes. Double taking up 8 bytes, this will overflow your allocation (12+8 > 16), mentioned above.

You most likely want to change the allication to `stars[i] = malloc(sizeof(Star));`, to allocate the proper amount of space for your struct.

EDIT:
If you are planning to use the allocated data elsewhere, you should remove the call to `free`, and instead free the data after you are done with it in your program. The `return` statement on the following line may possibly be a mistake too, as it exits the loop on the first iteration, which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: You forgot to mention _removing_ the `free(stars[i])`. And, the `return 1;` will stop on the _first_ iteration, and so should be removed as well.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, good catch, I was focused on simply answering the segfault issue. Edited the answer.